# Issue with Red wire to a remote controlled ceiling fan replacement (14/3 to 14/2 wires)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

The Situation:  20 yr old Ceiling fan replacement with a remote controlled new fan.

I have two wall switches: one controls 3 ceiling canned lights in the kitchen and one provides power to the ceiling fan.  The old ceiling fan light and speed were controlled by pull chains.

New Ceiling fan:  Remote controlled.  Has a receiver with a black and white wire to connect to the ceiling wiring.  On the other side the receiver has a blue, black, white to connect to the ceiling fan motor.

The ceiling fan junction box has a 14/3 that is wired together with a 14/2 to bring power to the other 3 lights in the ceiling with the ceiling fan box in the middle.

The extra red wire goes to the one wall switch that controlled the power for the old ceiling fan.

I originally capped the red wire but I don't want to have to turn all lights on for the ceiling fan to work.

I want the one switch that has the red and black wire connected to it to control the power to the fan.  The remote will control everything else.

FYI: In the wall with the 2 switches, the white wire doesn't go to either switch, they are capped together in the back of the box.

I hope this makes sense.  I've seen contradicting info on the internet and hope someone here can advise me.

---

[image]

[image]

Red wire is capped in the ceiling box.  The blue and black from the fan go to the receiver.

The switch that's pulled out is the one that powered the original fan.  With the red wire capped at the ceiling only the canned lights switch on the right gave the new fan power.

---

[image: The receiver]

[image: The instructions]

Hope this helps.  And yes believe it or not, I have to tuck that receive in the hangar bracket!

Comment: Do you want the can lights to be controlled by the fan remote or by the wall switch?

Comment: Is it constructive to turn off the fan power with the switch? This will kill the remote dead, and you will no longer be able to turn the fan or light on/off with the remote.   I take it this is a wireless remote...

Comment: I'm trying to add pictures but the site is telling me I can only add two then doesn't add them.  Anyway,  I want to be able to power the fan and it's light by the switch without having to turn on the canned lights as well.  Right now the fan switch does nothing because the red wire is capped.

Comment: Post the pictures to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and link them in the comments, then we can edit them into your post.  Can you replace that 14/3 with a new run of cable by the way?

Comment: @Harper To use the remore, all lights in the kitchen must be on.  See the dilemma?

Comment: @ThreePhase  Nope, not running new wire through a finished cathedral ceiling and walls.  The switch turned on the power to the old fan and I'd used the pull chains to control the speed and light.  I want to use the switch the same way with the new fan except I'm using the remote to control the speed and light.

Comment: I'm thinking the red in the ceiling needs to be wired to either the black wires or cap the two black wires for the circuit to work in the ceiling box and attach the red to the black wire to the receiver???

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, that won't work.  The pull chains were mechanical switches, that stayed in the last position they were left in.   *You will lose that functionality.*. When you sever power to the control module, it will lose its memory and forget which position it was last in.  It will start up at "whatever".  You will have to grab the remote and choose the desired setting everytime you power up with the switch,

Comment: Honestly Harper, that's fine with me.  The canned kitchen lights that have to be on for the fan to work the way I had it wired is a problem.  I call those canned lights "french fry cookers" 'cause they add so much heat to the kitchen.  The ceiling fan is in the same room but over the dining room table.

Comment: Is it OK if the fan is independently controllable, but all the lights work off the remote?

Comment: Are you OK with ditching the existing fan remote in favor of a wallbox mounted control, for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  What wall control do you suggest?  That would work for me just fine.

Comment: Do you want an IR remote that you have to point at the wallbox like having to point your TV remote at the TV, or do you want a radio remote that isn't as...directional?  Or do you just want wallbox control, and don't mind not having a handheld remote to begin with?

Comment: I've seen the wall mounted speed controllers with a remote and that's not necessary.  I'm looking for a wall speed and light control that i can preset and has an on/off switch on it.  I found a Levitron on Amazon but it has knobs you turn and read that it's hard to grip them so I passed that one up.